# Детский вопрос: числительные на «-иллион»

Tags: словообразование, числительные, морфемный-разбор

Все началось с квадрата.
Подыскивали однокоренные слова: квадратик, квадратный, квадратура, [квадриллион](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD)...
Объяснила ребенку, что это особенное числительное, что оно имеет два корня: *квадр* + *иллион*.

«Какие "иллионные" числа есть еще?»
Посмотрели: триллион (*-триллион-*), миллион (*-миллион-*), биллион (*-биллион-*), квинтиллион (*квинт/иллион*), секстиллион, септиллион...

Так что же такое "иллион" — корень, часть корня или суффикс?

[Большие числа](https://thebridgestudio.ru/chislo-s-10-nulyami-nazvanie-kak-nazyvaetsya-samoe-bolshoe-chislo-v.html)
[Морфемно-орфографический словарь Тихонова](http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-k.htm)

Answer (score 3):

По крайней мере ещё один из онлайн ресурсов по морфемному разбору с вами согласен и выделяет два корня в слове
[квадриллион](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9A/%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD), но при этом *миллион*, *миллиард*, *биллион*, и [триллион](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A2/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD) считает единым корнем.

На мой взгляд, деление достаточно условное, но почему бы нет?

Слова эти заимствованы из французского, где (за исключением *миллиона*) были [искусственно образованы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B5,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0), когда математикам захотелось как-то называть подобные [большие числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

С точки зрения французского и английского языков *-illion* - это основа (*stem*), полученная из слова *million* отбрасыванием первой буквы, и все последующие названия чисел (за исключением, разумеется, *milliard*) получены путём добавления латинского **префикса** (bi-, tri- и т.д.). (Wiki: [Names of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers), ссылается на "p. 316, The History of the English Language, Oliver Farrar Emerson, New York, London: Macmillan and Co., 1894.") То есть, в английском/французском *quadr-* и т.д. продолжают считать префиксами, что вполне логично.

[*Для читающих по-английски может быть также интересно начало [этой статьи](https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/2-4/2)*.]